# GridLayout not displaying JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, grid-layout

I currently have `GridLayout(3,0)` and I want to add some buttons. However, nothing shows up when I run my program.

Here is the code (the class extends `JFrame`):

```
public void initializeGraphics() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1900, 1000));
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    setVisible(true);

    createMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void createMenu() {
    JPanel menuArea = new JPanel();
    menuArea.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));

    menuArea.setBounds(40,40,740,870);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("test1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("test2");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("test3");
    menuArea.add(button1);
    menuArea.add(button2);
    menuArea.add(button3);

    add(menuArea);
}
```

Comment: *setLayout(new BorderLayout()); ... getContentPane().setLayout(null);* What's happening there? You set a layout then immediately remove it...

Comment: Don’t use `setLayout(null)`.  You can put panels inside panels, so create JPanels with the layouts that actually fit your needs.  Since you seem to want a 40 pixel margin above and left of your menu, use `menuArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(40, 0, 0, 40));`, then add menuArea to a BorderLayout with the LINE_START constraint (or WEST constraint).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your UI component before setting visible attributes.

edit your code as:

```
createMenu();
setVisible(true);
```